# AWS Cognito User Pool Sign In Missing Authentication Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin.forms, amazon-cognito

I am trying to authenticate my user in a Xamarin Forms cross platform app using AWS Cognito User Pools.

I am able to sign up a user using the SignUpAysnc() and I can see it populate in the user pool in the AWS console.

```
CognitoUserPool userPool = AmazonUtils.UserPool;
Dictionary<string, string> userAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

userAttributes.Add("email", email);
userAttributes.Add("given_name", given_name);
userAttributes.Add("family_name", family_name);
userAttributes.Add("gender", gender);
userAttributes.Add("birthdate", birthdate);
userAttributes.Add("address", address);
userAttributes.Add("locale", locale);
userAttributes.Add("phone_number", phone_number);

await userPool.SignUpAsync(email, Password, userAttributes, null);
```

However when I try to use the email and password provided to sign in I keep getting this exception:

```
[0:] Missing Authentication Token
```

My current authentication code is:

```
private async void LoginButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AdminInitiateAuthRequest authRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest();
    authRequest.ClientId = Constants.ClientID;
    authRequest.AuthParameters.Add("email", "test.user@email.com");
    authRequest.AuthParameters.Add("password", "Password12!");
    authRequest.UserPoolId = Constants.AuthPoolID;
    authRequest.AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH;

    try
    { 
        AdminInitiateAuthResponse response = await AmazonUtils.IdentityClientProvider.AdminInitiateAuthAsync(authRequest);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you need to initiate the authentication challenge first, and then pass password as well as encrypted string, that contains pool name, username, secret block and other information.

This is a good .Net example: http://blog.mmlac.com/aws-cognito-srp-login-c-sharp-dot-net/

Note that you need to add Org.BouncyCastle.Math and Org.BouncyCastle.Security via NuGet to your project in order to compile it.

There is another example: https://gist.github.com/dbeattie71/44ea3a13145f185d303e620c299ab1c5

It looks promising, but I did not check it so I can't guaranty that it works. From it you could get an understanding on how overall process looks like.

Comment: Thanks that has put me on the right track. Unfortunately I am trying to get it to work in a PCL so I am getting errors with missing references to HashAlgorithm. I can see there is a reference to HashAlgorithm in the System.Security.Cryptography dll (developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Security.Cryptography/) Any ideas?

Comment: @PoodleGalluzzo Great to hear! :) System.Security.Cryptography would not work, you need to find BouncyCastle.Security PCL port, last time I checked, there was a few of them in NuGet.